# How to Rotate an object about its own axis?

Tags: c#, math, 3d, rotation, geometry

I'm having a problem working out how to solve a problem.

My problem involves getting the 3D representation of an objects angle, and then applying a rotation to that object on it's own axis.

For example, an aircraft with:

- Heading 45 (North East)
- Pitch 45 (Nose Up)
- Bank 45 (Banked Left)

That is rotated across it's own yaw axis through -90 degrees should then be roughly:

- Heading ~-9.8 (North by North North West)
- Pitch -30 (Nose Down)
- Bank 54.5 (Banked Left)

(As calculated purely off guesstimation using another program to make the aircraft a child of itself and rotate through 90 degrees, then trying to match the orientation...)

Can anyone explain how this sort of rotation is calculated? or even point me into the right path as to learning how?

I have tried applying a basic rotation matrix to the angles (as to be used for rotating points about an origin), but it only rotates relative to the base x/y/z axes and not that of the aircraft (so results from above would be (-45,45,45)

For mathematics purposes, the rotation does not concern point co-ordinates, only the 3 representation angles.

I would prefer not to use any external libraries.

Though irrelevant, this will be for a C# application.

Thank you all very much for your help and insight!

Answer (score 1):

The rotation matrix is a good start, but you'll need a Translation matrix as well to get the origin right.

You'll need linear algebra with rotation matrices if you want to do it by hand. It require some mathematics skills.

Basically this (below) states: move the object to the origin of x/y/z/, apply the rotation matrix and put it back at the original position.

I must warn you, it's hard to get it right by hand.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

As a acquaintance of mine put it once:

r'j(t) = r'0(t) + Ω(t) x [rj(t) - r0(t)]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem

Comment: Hi.

I am not using co-ordinates. just angles! There are no points to move!

Comment: @DwayneBrumby: Don't you use distances somewhere? You stated there are some x/y/z axis. You say the object needs to rotate around it's own axis, an object implies that you are not just working with a set of angles?

Comment: Hi again. I'm writing an API for closed source code, so I'm only able to get the position of the object, and it's rotation. The position doesn't concern me, as I am not wanting to change its position, just the angle.

Comment: @DwayneBrumby: Hi, what i am trying to say: if you want to rotate your object with a rotation matrix, it is necessary to set a origin for the rotation. This is exactly what you are doing by putting your object in the origin of your x/y/z/ axis. If you rotate the object at this point, it will rotate in respective to its center. After that put it back and you'll have a rotated object at an arbitrary position. The re-positioning is really simple (provided your axis are orthogonal), just subtract and add x,y,z, points of the object with the x,y,z, coordinates of the center of the object.

Comment: Let me know if you want to try it this way; if I got some time to spare I am willing to help you with this one. Good luck.

Comment: I understand what you are saying: to rotate the point 1,0,0 of a model at position 5,5,6 through 45 degrees, you first get the points current position (6,5,6) then subtract object center (1,0,0) then perform the rotation matrix (0.707, 0, -0.707) then you add the object center again...

That is NOT my problem.

I have ANGLES, not co-ordinates. I am trying to rotate an angle, relative to it's own axis.

for example, the orientation defined by angles (0,0,30), rotated by (0, 90, 0) should become (45, 77.94, 90). I am struggling with the relationships between the axis that result in these results

Comment: I may state that the model is angled at 0,0,0 by default, then rotated on the x axis by the first value, then it's y axis by value 2, then z axis by value 3 (so, Euler angles).

Take this gif for example: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Euler2a.gif/170px-Euler2a.gif

I am wishin to perform a 4th rotation on any of the 3 red axis, AFTER the initial rotation is completed. (and thus get the new representation)

Comment: @DwayneBrumby: oh ... lol, I totally misunderstood. I will come back to you on this one when I finished work ;)

Comment: I think I have the solution: i need to convert the euler references from instrinsic to extrinsice, then apply the change, then convert BACK to instrinsic.